# Несколько соединений с БД или одно подключение с помощью статического класса?

Tags: mysqli, php

За время работы некоторого php-скрипта происходит 2 (а может быть, и 3) соединения с БД mysql. Например, при первом соединении из БД извлекаются темы статей для вывода в анонсах. Во втором - непосредственно какая-то статья на главной странице. Получается, объект mysqli создается и уничтожается 2 раза. Если я надумаю прикрутить еще какую-нибудь фишку, то придется и 3-й раз создавать соединение и т.д., потому что за каждые такие вещи отвечают разные Контроллеры и Модели.

Вопрос такой: не разумнее ли будет в целях оптимизации в начале работы скрипта создать объект статического класса, который один раз установит соединение с БД, а его свойства и методы можно будет использовать там, где это необходимо на протяжении всей работы серверного скрипта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких вещей используют паттерн [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_PHP_5)

Comment: Спасибо, а вот статья в самую точку - http://www.andrey-vasiliev.com/php/prakticheskaya-realizaciya-patterna-singleton-na-php/